# Using libusb on Android without rooting

Tags: android, permissions, android-ndk, usb, libusb

I am trying to communicate with USB device from Android-based smartphone via OTG. I was able to communicate with my device using Android USB Host API. The problem of USB Host API solution is performance (single bulk transfer bounded by 16384 bytes).

The libusb can perform larger requests and now I am trying to integrate it using Android NDK. I succeeded to compile libusb sources for Android and even `initUSB()`, but `libusb_open(dev, &dev_handle)` returns -3 (Access denied).

How can I pass the file descriptor

```
int fd = connection.getFileDescriptor()
```

to libusb after getting USB_PERMISSION under Android USB Host API and get USB device access under libusb?

Comment: try this libusb fork https://github.com/martinmarinov/rtl_tcp_andro-/tree/master/jni/libusb-andro. it has open2(, int fd) function for this

Comment: vote to get good explanation from android team: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56450

Answer (score 5):

This is what you are looking for.
https://github.com/kuldeepdhaka/libusb/tree/android-open2
just compile it and drop it in. :)
see the "How To for Android" section for full usage.

i made all the required modification to libusb (and im also using it).
It has SELinux fix for "Android 5.0"+ too.

Comment: That sounds promising, I've looked at your github project but I'm still not sure how to use it.  Are you using jni to call libusb from java code?

Comment: @dweebo Yes, Java -> JNI -> libusb

Comment: @dweebo Everything is here https://gitlab.com/madresistor. Contact me  (kuldeep on #madresistor on Freenode) (or mail me  - kuldeepdhaka9 gmail thing) - i can explain it you in detail.

Comment: How is this github different from the main github: https://github.com/libusb/libusb ?

Comment: Is it still relevant? It would be useful for handling USB audio class 2

Comment: Did you ever submit anytihng as a PR to the main repo?

Comment: I looked for one under your github name but didn't find one.  A bit ago I opened https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/862 .

Answer (score 3):

See also https://github.com/libusb/libusb/wiki/Android which now discusses android a little bit.  Here is the quote from the proposed readme change (2021-02):

```
Runtime Permissions:
--------------------

The Runtime Permissions on Android can be transfered from Java to Native over the following approach:
 Java:
  // obtaining the Usb Permissions over the android.hardware.usb.UsbManager class
  usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
  HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usbManager.getDeviceList();
  for (UsbDevice usbDevice : deviceList.values()) {   usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, mPermissionIntent); }
  // get the native FileDescriptor of the UsbDevice and transfer it to Native over JNI or JNA
  UsbDeviceConnection usbDeviceConnection = usbManager.openDevice(camDevice);
  int fileDescriptor = usbDeviceConnection.getFileDescriptor();
  // JNA sample method: 
  JNA.INSTANCE.set_the_native_Descriptor(fileDescriptor);  
 Native:
  // Initialize LibUsb on Android
  set_the_native_Descriptor(int fileDescriptor) {
   libusb_context *ctx;
   libusb_device_handle *devh;
   libusb_set_option(&ctx, LIBUSB_OPTION_WEAK_AUTHORITY, NULL);        // important for Android
   libusb_init(&ctx);
   libusb_wrap_sys_device(NULL, (intptr_t)fileDescriptor, &devh);

   //  From this point you can regulary use all LibUsb functions as usual.
  }
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/libusb/libusb/pull/874 which makes non-rooted work better.  Please update the wiki if needed.  Please contribute work to improve things if you can.